# How do I append to a file using the COPY command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7-x64

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64, but my experience dates back to DOS 3.0.

Since like DOS 3.1 you've been able to append a file to another one with this use of the COPY command:

```
COPY FILE1+FILE2=FILE1
```

Making the need for a temporary FILE3 unnecessary.

It was a very convenient command since whenever you added a new program you often needed to update your `CONFIG.SYS` and `AUTOEXEC.BAT` files.

It also used to be that getting the order correct was importiant, otherwise you'd end up with an empty FILE1.

But today when I tried that, it left `FILE1` untouched, and when I reversed the order, it (understandably) made `FILE1`  a copy of `FILE2`.

Does anyone know if it's been replaced with another method, and when this change happened?

**EDIT:**

I've been doing more testing, and oddly even though the above code won't work, you still can sill copy from the console and append that to an existing file like this:

```
copy file1+con=file1
Type some text to append to file1
^Z ([CTRL]+Z the End Of File character)
```

I'm wondering if my version of Windows is messed up somehow.  Can any body replicate my findings?

**EDIT:**

It works on 95 / 98 / ME / 2000 / XP / XP Mode / 7 Professional x64 / 8 x64. So I imagine that it's not a `7 Ultimate x64` problem, but rather an issue with my machine.

*** Sigh *

**EDIT:**

Last edit, I promise. :)

It was not an issue with my machine, it was an issue with File1.  Apparently when I first appended File2 to it, the [CTRL]+Z (EOF character) never got overwritten, causing the file to look like this:

```
Original Data
Original Data
[EOF]
Appended Data
Appended Data
Appended Data
```

You can duplicate this yourself with the following experiment from at the command prompt. (Where ^Z is the character [CTRL]+Z )

At the command prompt type:

```
copy con file1
File One
^Z^Z

copy con file2
File Two
^Z

copy con file3
File Three
^Z

copy file1+file2=file1

copy file2+file3=file2

TYPE file1
TYPE file2
```

You will see:

`file1`

```
File One
```

`file2`

```
File Two
File Three
```

You can `type file2 >> file1` or use nearly any other method of concatenating files, and when you type `file1` it will still only appear to contain `File One`. BUT if you use `FIND "searchterm" file` to parse the file it will show you what's REALLY going on.  In this case type:

```
FIND " " file1
```

And you will be rewarded with:

```
---------- FILE1
File One
→File Two
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Windows 8 x86:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Nikos>echo foo>file1

C:\Users\Nikos>echo bar>file2

C:\Users\Nikos>copy /b file1 + file2 file1
file1
file2
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\Nikos>type file1
foo
bar
```

Comment: what do you get when copying foo+bar=foo?

Comment: I get the original version of foo.

Comment: I have verified that `copy file1+file2=file1` works on Windows 7 Professional x64, so I believe that it's probably my machine.

Comment: Thanks for helping me figure this out. :)

Comment: Is there any way to retrieve file2 and file1 again using command??

Comment: to retrieve the files you would need to have some splitter tool and to know the lengths of the files in it

Answer (score 7):

What about `type file2 >> file1`

Comment: @JamesK You never stated "binary" in your question. What exactly do you want to do then?

Comment: @EitanT - I'm just wondering if that functionality has disappeared from windows because it's more efficient than any other built-in method of concatenation of files, binary OR text.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work either. The problem is that the file got two EOF characters at the end of it, so when appending using almost any method, one EOF character survives with the appended text coming after it.

Answer (score 6):

Answer to: "**How do I append to a file using the COPY command**"

**WARNING**: If you have a list of files you wish to combine via COPY command, it's simple but can potentially destroy your files.

**Dangerous Way**:

`copy /b one + two + three` -- will append contents of "two" and "three" to the file "one" . So the original "one" now has contents of 3 files in proper sequence. If during copy-process things go wrong, you'll have no way of recovering original "one", as it will be corrupt and your data would essentially be lost. There's almost Never a reason to use this way.

**Safe Way**:

`copy /b one + two new_filename` -- will combine 2 files (you can list more than two of course), creating a new_filename containing "one" and "two" in proper sequence, and leaving original files intact.

Comment: For me, this is best solution so far.  I want to append one text file to another.  This is easiest method:   copy destin_file  new_file   appends new_file onto destin_file

Comment: @DougNull That will not work actually. If you only have 2 files like this: *copy File_1 File2* what will happen is copy will not do appending it will create a copy of File1 and name it File2. If File2 exists it will overwrite it. I updated my answer to the two-file scenario

Answer (score 2):

make sure you start with fresh files you never tried to copy over.
I just found that on my (XP sp3) `copy a+b a` without `/b` appends `1A` (`SUB`) to the end of the file which makes anything after it disappear from output of `type` (but `more` will show it). `Copy /b a+b a` works.

Comment: Yes, I was able to confirm that it works on XP. Well, XP Mode anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

cls

type "file2.txt" >> "file1.txt"

exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `copy /b file1 + file2 file1`

Comment: Yes. I've tried every iteration I can think of and every one I've run across.

Answer (score 1):

`copy /b input1 + input2 output`
`del input1`
`ren output input1`
Maybe this? :P

Comment: Sure, even `copy /b file1 + file2 file3` `move file3 file1` works. I'm not trying to replace the functionality, I'm trying to discover if it's been removed from the COPY command (and when), or if my computer is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\Nikos>type file1
foo
bar

C:\Users\Nikos>copy file1+con=file1
file1
con
ihdui
ohisd
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\Nikos>type file1
foo
bar
ihdui
ohisd
```

Answer (score 1):

Wait! There is more!  (Win7 Pro)

```
>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]

>copy file.a.txt + file.b.txt file.ab.txt
file.a.txt
1 file(s) copied

>copy fileA.txt + fileB.txt fileAB.txt
fileA.txt
fileB.txt
1 files(s) copied
```

Putting aside the "1 file(s) copied" notification, it just doesn't like files with funny names.

Answer (score 1):

To copy to a binary file ...

Put all files in same folder e.g. `G:\Files`

```
g:
cd Files
copy /B *.* TargetFilename.ext
```

and `.ext` is the type of file required

Answer (score 0):

```
        echo . 2>new.mp3
        rem create a new empty.
        for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.mp3') do copy /b "%cd%\new.mp3"+"%cd%\%%i.mp3" %cd%\new.mp3
        
        rem loop merge mp3 to new.mp3
        rem or you can edit a list to merge files
        for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do copy /b "%cd%\new.mp3"+"%cd%\%%i.mp3" %cd%\new.mp3
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Put all the files in the same folder.
2. `copy *.* ´target.ext'`
3. ????
4. Profit!