# Append lines of text file with lines from another text file

Tags: windows, command-line, text-files

I only have access to windows and its command line.

I have two text files with many lines, file1 and file2.  I want to append the lines in file1 with the corresponding lines from file2.

Each line in file1 looks like this:

```
apple Orange
```

Each line in file2 looks like this:

```
banana
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
apple Orangebanana
```

Any ideas? Preferably via win command prompt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I append to a file using the COPY command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342764/how-do-i-append-to-a-file-using-the-copy-command)

Comment: @Im0rtality the referenced link covers merging text files by appending them one after the other whereas I want to append files line by line, similar to this linux example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394176/how-to-merge-two-files-consistently-line-by-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` as input files and interleaves them into `result.txt`

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
(
< file2.txt (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
      set file2Line=
      set /P file2Line=
      set "file1Line=%%a"
      setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion   
      echo(!file1Line!!file2Line!
      endlocal
   )
)
)>"result.txt"

pause
```